# Best way to handle reserved names in a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on the model of a Rails app and half of the names I need to use are reserved (and they are also the ones that make more sense within the application. I don't want to find another name). What's the best way to handle this?

I am thinking of using a prefix for all the models (for the ones with reserved words and not) My ideas for "Process":

**MyProcess**

**TheProcess**

So whatever prefix I choose, I will use it for every model:

**MyUser**

**TheUser**

Thanks!

Comment: Which reserved names are you talking about?

Comment: Process, Monitor, Signal, Action

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to avoid name clashes is namespacing. That is, you put all your "reserved" names (and all of the others, for consistency) in a module. Something like this:

```
module MyApp
  class Signal
    # code here
  end
end
```

This way, while within `MyApp`, `Signal` means your class and `::Signal` will be the one from ruby.